# Cannot read checkbox when not ticked

Tags: node.js, express, dom, checkbox

I am trying to check if a checkbox is ticked but when the checkbox is not ticked it wont work and gives the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'PrivateCheck' of undefined" and points to the line with this code:

```
let isprivare = req.body['PrivateCheck'];
```

This is the check box I am trying to get input from

```
<form class="fileupload" action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="checkbox" id="PrivateCheck" name="PrivateCheck" />
</form>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the HTML documentation the value of a checkbox is sent with the form only if it is checked. Otherwise nothing is sent for that checkbox.

In your particular case you can fix it like this:

```
let isprivate = req.body && req.body['PrivateCheck'];
```

Comment: is correct. Other thing you can do is use lodash's get function.